# What is Vertica UDS DataBuffer.buff[] maximum size(how to override it)?

Tags: java, vertica

I have written a Vertica user defined source which reads data from a URL and copies it into specified Vertica table, via Vertica COPY command. However, when I do

`offset = reader.read(output.buf, output.offset, output.buf.length - output.offset);`

inside

`public StreamState process(ServerInterface srvInterface, DataBuffer output)`

method only **16384** bytes of data gets copied into **output.buf**. Any value of offset and length doesn't have any impact on this. **output.buf** always seem to have **16384** data. If I print **offset** in the logs it always shows **16384**. However, when I print **output.buf.length** it shows **1048576**, while the actual size of the data I want to copy is of **127607** bytes.

Could someone please guide me towards the correct way of doing this? I tried looking into the Vertica docs and tried Googling it as well, but could not find any help.

Is **16384** the **maximum** number of bytes that **output.buf** can accomodate? If that is the case what's the correct way to increase it to a higher value.

Thank you so much for your valuable time. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I'd recommend posting this on the [Vertica community](https://community.dev.hp.com/t5/Vertica-Forum/bd-p/bigdata_forums_vertica)

Comment: @Kermit I did,but to no avail!

Comment: I don't know vertica, nor do I know what type `reader` is, but if it is anything like a normal `InputStream` or `Reader`, then you should be prepared for cases where a `read` doesn't return or process all requested bytes. As 16384 is 2^14, my guess that it would be the size of an internal buffer. You probably need to loop until all bytes you want to process have been processed.